# how to calculate the max, min and avg in reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm very new to report viewer and I'm sorry if I can't ask here but here it goes
I have this kind of report:

[image]

On the field Max, I would like to show only the max value between all the data of the field Time
for example, this should return only 95. is there possible to be done?

I have tried to do that:

```
=Max(Fields!timertempo.Value,"DataSet1")
```

But the same result repeats in all the report

[image]

The first one should be 95, the second 122 and the third 94 and so on
is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to group this data by the first and second column ("Place" and "Operator") respectively. If you have done this already as I can see in the screenshot above, you need to get the max of every group. the syntax for the Max function is as follow :

```
Max(expression, scope, recursive)
```

Please check the following Link: [Max in SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-max-function?view=sql-server-ver15)

So, we you need to adjust is making the expression like this :

```
=max(Fields!time.Value,"Place")
```

The place here is the group name. This will produce the exact output that you need.
[image]

I do not know your exact business needs but I hope that this is helpful.